# Angular use ng-src in an image tag within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have used ng-src on img tags many times within ng-repeats with success, but for some reason I can't get this one to work.

I have an API call that returns some data, and for each item in the return, I basically do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in APIreturn">
    <img ng-src="{{item.url}}" />
</div>
```

I have also tried `src="{{item.url}}"`, `ng-src="item.url"` and so forth.  I've verified that the url that is being used is valid, and works fine in `src="{{item.url}}"` outside of the ng-repeat.

Any ideas why it would be different in the ng-repeat?

Current HTML

```
<table ng-repeat="user in userInformation">
    <tr>
        <td>UserName:</td>
        <td>{{user.UserName}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Address:</td>
        <td>{{user.Address}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gender:</td>
        <td>{{user.Gender}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Image:</td>
        <td><img ng-src"user.image" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image: These are both using the same element in this object...but for some reason the image render]

Comment: The final HTML might be helpful.

Comment: Just posted it for you. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you see url if you use just <td>{{ user.image }}</td>? user.image or user.Image?

Comment: change to `<img ng-src= "user.image" />`

Comment: Sorry, yes it is showing.  But the same attribute doesn't show the image in the image tag.

Comment: Well, you found the error. Try {{ user | json }} to see more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you don't see the url if you put just `<td>{{ user.image }}</td>`. This indicate you access not existing property on yout object. Try [json filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/json):

```
<td>{{ user | json }}</td>
```

to see more of your object. As I can see, you use capital letters, but `user.image` is lower cased.

EDIT: here is a working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8lHk4gFx7wThtJf5rRe5?p=preview).

EDIT2: you missing assign sign.

Comment: I was mistaken, and tried to correct my comment.  The image that I just posted above shows your suggestion of printing just the url. It is being printed, and the img src is using the exact same attribute that is being printed below it.

Comment: See my edit2. You wrote ng-src"{{ instead of ng-src="{{

Comment: Thanks Anton! That was it.

Answer (score 2):

try change to this. i think you forgot put `=` after `ng-src` .

```
  <tr>
    <td>Image:</td>
    <td><img ng-src = "user.image" /></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Thank you for catching that.  That was it.

Answer (score 0):

See [Strict Contextual Escaping](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service.

Angular unsafes img src attributes so you'll need to trust it in order to make your images available.

Another approach is to use [css to render the images](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp):

Answer (score 0):

For table, in *ng-repeat*, you have to use `{{}}` this interpolation in order to access the src file.
Try this one:

```
<td><img ng-src = "{{user.image}}"/></td>
```

Let me know if any issues.